# Contact Form 7 returns validation errors in Nuxt3 application

Tags: contact-form-7, wordpress-rest-api

I've got a Nuxt3 application that I am building for a client that uses a headless Wordpress instance for the backend. In the footer is a newsletter signup feature, so I installed the Contact Form 7 and Flamingo plugins to capture the emails.

When I test the endpoint in Insomnia, I get a successful result back and can verify the email is being stored in Wordpress. When I submit via my application however, I get back validation errors:

```json
{
    "contact_form_id": 921,
    "status": "validation_failed",
    "message": "One or more fields have an error. Please check and try again.",
    "invalid_fields": [
        {
            "field": "your-email",
            "message": "Please fill out this field.",
            "idref": null,
            "error_id": "-ve-your-email"
        }
    ],
    "posted_data_hash": "",
    "into": "#"
}
```

Here is the code I am running to submit from the frontend:

```js
try {
      const runtimeConfig = useRuntimeConfig();
      const body = new FormData();

      body.append('your-email', email.value);
      body.append('your-subject', 'Newsletter Subscription');
      body.append('your-message', 'A user has subscribed to the newsletter.');
      body.append('your-name', 'Corporation USA');

      const res = await $fetch<NewsletterResponse>(`${runtimeConfig.public.NEWSLETTER_ENDPOINT}`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
        body,
      });
      console.log({ res });
      email.value = '';
    } catch (err: any) {
      console.log({ err });
    } finally {
      submitting.value = false;
    }
```

I have verified that the email is being passed in to the payload with a key of `your-email`. What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

After implementing Cloudflare security and disabling reCAPTCHA, I encountered an issue with the Contact Form 7 plugin indicating "One or more fields have an error. Please check and try again." However, the solution was straightforward: by adding Cloudflare Turnstile just before the submit button in the form, everything returned to functioning correctly. I appreciate the seamless integration! If you need to make similar adjustments, remember to modify the form template to include the Simple Cloudflare Turnstile Plugin  [cf7-simple-turnstile]  right before the submit action. Everything is working splendidly now. More info https://community.cloudflare.com/t/how-could-i-implement-turnstile-with-form-7/423973!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).